# Multiplication of convolutions

Tags: calculus, integration

I'd like to figure out why

$\int (f \text{_} \ast f (x))(K \ast K(x)) dx = \int (K \ast f)^2 (x) dx$

and

$\int (f \text{_} \ast f(x)) K(x) dx = \int (K \ast f (x)) f(x) dx$

hold, where $ f \text{_}(x) = f(-x)$, and $f,K$ are both non-negative functions.

For the second equation I thought that because of the non-negativity Tonelli might apply, so I could could change the order of integration which leads me to the result, but I'm not sure if this is correct. For the first one, I do not really have an idea how to rearrange.

Does anyone have an idea?